# Dual boot Windows OS automatic configuration

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, vmware, bcd, vcenter

After soom manipulation with temporary connected another `Win10` operating system installed on another HDD I got complicated situation wih my current `Win 8 OS`. I hadn't drive `E:` previously and I think I got some automatic win 10 boot managment while both OS HDD was connected on my PC.

Currently I have situation when only Win8 drive is connected and I have two drives:

[image]

Content of E: disc:

[image]

System is botting and operational, but I don't like it anyway, because I have some PC virtualization issuer while using Vmare vCenter converter.

```
 Error Reconfiguration failed. With a status of: FAILED: Unable to find the system volume, reconfiguration is not possible.
```

I suppose vCenter is confused because strange system disc structure. How to make my system disc to previous (not dual disc) state?

Comment: Besides the fact you have a drive letter assigned to a volume, that doesn't need one which can easily be removed, what is your question?

Comment: Why I have such partition at all? Why boot files are located in E: drive and not in C: ?

Comment: The partition always existed it was just hidden before.  The system now has a drive letter only because of your other actions.